# android googleMap- how to get clickEvent for myLocation marker?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-api-2

I have enabled the google map mylocation marker  by the following:

```
googleMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

then it will show the following:[image]

but now i want a click event when user touches this marker. how can i get this. i dont see anything exposed to get the event, can you help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the onMyLocationClickListener provided by GoogleMaps. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener

Comment: i thought that as for this button circled in red my question is about the marker, not the icon above.  : https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjCke-MtuzlAhXHLlAKHaUGBj0QjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27010991%2Fenable-my-location-icon-googlemap-v2&psig=AOvVaw12NEEMREEFcLtEiHVV5zT4&ust=1573914360088932

Comment: I believe that is GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back on the Razvan's answer with a code sample, It is possible:

```
googleMap!!.setOnMyLocationClickListener { location -> 
   Log.d("My Location", "onMyLocationClick() called with: location = [$location]") 
}
```

where `googleMap` is the `GoogleMap` instance from onMapReadyCallback